# Increase variables in For statement

Tags: vb.net

I have this part of code into a visual basic project...

```
        Dim fileReader1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName)
        Dim Part1A = "<b id=""Blahblah"">"
        Dim Part1B = "</b>"
        Dim fileSplit1 = fileReader1.Split(New String() {Part1A}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        fileReader1 = fileSplit1.Last
        fileSplit1 = fileReader1.Split(New String() {Part1B}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        fileReader1 = fileSplit1.First
```

...and I am trying to make a loop for it to increase number `1` for all variables. Something like this...

```
            For i As Integer = 1 To 10
                Dim ("fileReader" & i) = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                ...
            Next
```

...but I get errors! Any idea how should be the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, variables do not like to be named like this.  However, you could use an array:

```
Dim fileReader(10) as String

For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    fileReader(i) = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim Part1A = "<b id=""Blahblah"">"
    Dim Part1B = "</b>"
    Dim fileSplit1 = fileReader(i).Split(New String() {Part1A}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    fileReader(i) = fileSplit1.Last
    fileSplit1 = fileReader(i).Split(New String() {Part1B}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    fileReader(i) = fileSplit1.First
Next
```

The rest of your code would be fine, you would just need to change every instance of fileReader1 to fileReader(i).

If it is necessary for Part1A and Part1B to be have unique values for each i, you would make an array in the same way:

```
Dim fileReader(10) as String
Dim PartA(10) as String
Dim PartB(10) as String

For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    fileReader(i) = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim PartA(i) = "<b id=""Blahblah"">"
    Dim PartB(i) = "</b>"
    Dim fileSplit1 = fileReader(i).Split(New String() {PartA(i)}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    fileReader(i) = fileSplit1.Last
    fileSplit1 = fileReader(i).Split(New String() {PartB(i)}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    fileReader(i) = fileSplit1.First
Next
```

It is unnecessary, however, to put PartA and PartB into arrays if they will always have the same value, which they will have in the example you gave.  If the example remains the way it is, it is only necessary to change fileReader1 to fileReader(i).

Comment: I can use the same syntax for this part too `{Part1B}`? something like this `{Part(i)B}`?

Comment: I also need an example for this case `Dim Part1A`.

Comment: Yes, this would work in the same way, you would just use PartA(i) and PartB(i).  You will want to keep the array index at the end of the variable.  I will update my answer to show this change